# Unable to open the C source code of Emacs functions

Tags: emacs

When I search for a function description [find-function] and I click on the link to the "--.c"
file I cannot open it and I get Emacs C Source dir: ~/ in the Minibuf. I am stuck there and I don't know what to do.[image]

"The Emacs distribution includes the full source code for the manuals, as well as the Emacs Reference Card in several languages." gnu.org/software/emacs

Comment: Do you actually have the source to emacs somewhere on your machine?

Comment: @Wooble If I didn't could it run?! Emacs is working and all functions can be invoked.

Comment: Of course you could run it. The C code is compiled to a binary; you don't need the source code to run the binary.

Comment: @Wooble should I search for .el files? I have installed emacs from http://emacsformacosx.com/ and I guess it should have them. Can you advice me further?

Comment: If you want the C source, you need to download it. The Lisp source isn't going to have buffer.c in it.

Comment: @Wooble: "The Emacs distribution includes the full source code for the manuals, as well as the Emacs Reference Card in several languages." http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Get the `.tar.gz` file that corresponds to your Emacs version (check with `M-x emacs-version` if you're unsure) from http://ftp.gnu.org/pub/gnu/emacs/, and unpack it.  Then you can enter the path to where you unpacked it as response to "Emacs C Source Dir".  (I suspect you need to specify the `src` subdirectory of the Emacs distribution, but I haven't tried it myself.)

Answer (score 3):

After you download the soruce code, there is also a variable can custom the location of the source code. eg:

```
(setq find-function-C-source-directory "~/Projects/emacs-25.1/src/")
```